# Critique of those missing the Hard Problem?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, mind-body, david-chalmers, dennett

From everything I've ever seen about the [“Hard Problem of Consciousness”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness), the issue is that [materialists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialism) and [physicalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physicalism) presume a different question and answer that one instead.

I feel like the two parties are talking across each other. What I would like to know is whether this is what philosophers think too.

**Q1: Do dualists or other monists (consciousness, ideal) reply to phenomenal descriptions of consciousness by saying, “Youre not actually answering the hard problem.” ?**

The second less rigorous question is about the disjoint itself.

**Q2: Am I capturing what it is they are said to be missing? Alternatively, the second question might even be, “Would philosophers agree with, and even make, the distinctions I make?” about the hard problem.**

An angle of the second question is whether this is ultimately an [ontological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology) question, almost exclusively. Do my comments below capture *the way* in which respondents would push back?

(Please don’t downvote this just because you can divine what I believe. These very distinctions are exactly what’s not known by armchair philosophers.)

---

Hard Problem:

How do you explain that first-person, subjective consciousness as a raw, fundamental ontology is here? That qualia exist with their very own raw *being*, separate from the physical measurables.

**The hard problem is not simply that “We are super complex so how can matter be doing a human?” That's the easy problem.**

[Dennett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Dennett) and others then proceed with ever more complex (and possibly even more accurate) physical models/descriptions of biological functioning, mechanisms of the processing of perception, etc.

Dennet has most recently been saying we are like a trillion little robots who “accomplish” consciousness or elsewhere he says “gives rise to”.

However, no [philosophical dualist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism) (nor monist idealist) is arguing that it cannot be “accomplished” by the trillion robots. They want to know what you mean by “accomplished by”. Are they 1: just different names for the same thing (the trillions of robots and the [subjective experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenomenology_(philosophy))) or are they 2. in [cause-and-effect relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality) (as normally implied by “accomplished”) within a single [ontological category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_(Aristotle)), or does 3. this causation somehow cross ontological categories?

If 1 or 2, then it directly defies our personal data to claim they are the same ontology. If 3, then how does it cross? (If in your world, the color red is less real than cone and rods cells, then I can’t imagine that.)

**Q3**: Would addressing those numbered questions answer the problem? Is that the kind of thing people say? I imagine many readers of this question will want to argue that it *doesn't* miss the hard problem. That’s perfectly ok, but I am really asking what the philosophers who counter, who think it misses, would say. And if it matches some of the above or what?

Comment: Part of the hard problem is that there is no agreement on what the hard problem is. And all explanations supposed to clarify that must make presuppositions that already prejudge the approach, there is no neutral ground. You can read a sampling of philosophers' opinions on [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/hard-con/), but you will not find much new there. All options 1-3 are in circulation, discussions hit the same dead ends. And philosophers especially are not very deterred by "directly defying personal data". That data (or rather what it's taken to mean) has been much discredited in recent centuries.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the link. And the answer. a. I would say that discrediting the reliability of conscious reality is 0% of the way to discrediting its reality. In every way I can think of to assess “how real”, the sensations in my head are more real than the electrical impulses measured, the mri of the muscles, the models of pain transmission, and the matter making my skull. But I recognize that is fully one side and is an opinion. b, In retrospect, I am not at all surprised to hear defining the problem is much of it. I was even tryin

Comment: g to ask in unbiased way and having trouble. Maybe believing the hard problem exists *is* one’s position. But that would still mean others should try to motivate it is a nonquestion, not continue with technical explanations. Im really happy to hear I nailed 1,2,3 as key. Look forward to reading. Thanks again

Comment: @conifold do you agree with “But that would still mean..” previous comment

Comment: Excuse me for saying so, but part of the problem here is that the 'hard problem' of consciousness is sophomore-bait:: it is attractive to bright, energetic, enthusiastic brawlers who lack the skill and finesse of real philosophical thought. Dennett is a prime example: he goes after such concepts like a greyhound fixated on a mechanical rabbit, always convinced he's going to catch it and oblivious to anything he bowls over in his headlong rush. But unfortunately — on this topic — the sophs have taken over the classroom, and it's hard to get down to the real philosophy.

Comment: The 'hard problem' of consciousness boils down to a single question: What does it mean to 'experience'? Empiricists have always had difficulty with this philosophical question because everything in empiricism is supposed to rest on sensory experience; they tend to fall into a recursive quandary about it. Some of the (more sophomoric) hard-liners write the problem off by fiat: asserting that sensory experience is mechanistic (by virtue of being 'sensory'), and that this 'mechanisticness' percolates up to the rest of consciousness. Turtles all the way down, if you follow me...

Comment: They do motivate it. First, historically. Non-Euclidean geometry was taken to "defy personal data" not so long ago. Second, by analogy. Wittgenstein convinced many that many perceived problems are conceptual pseudo-problems that should be dissolved by dismantling artificial contexts that generate them. Physicalists, like Dennett, see the context of HPC as such an example. If we came to see heat as "another name" for Brownian motion then why not consciousness as "another name" for neurons' firing dynamics. But, in part, I agree with Ted, HPC did not prove philosophically fruitful so far.

Comment: @Conifold Lot of all three comments makes sense /informs. i guess most of what I hear is not attempts to motivate that hpc is a non-question. But im not a philosopher. Serious debates about that would be interesting, and the only question imo. Yes some who think it’s real problem claim current mechanisms are insufficient, you really could put penrose in that category, although he adds material too. But mostly that is not the point of the question, therefore yes dennetts dog chasing is tiresome. Im enjoying the hpc link. Goodnight

Comment: We're too far down the rabbit hole. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_zombie. To me the philosophical zombie is a perfectly coherent concept. The point is to illustrate that the standard "physical" properties at least as we understand them now... which are 3rd person do not necessarily entail phenomenal consciousness experience (or if they do, some kind of explanation needs to be given of how). It's bizarre to me that this would be controversial. It's like asking why does thunder (sound) follow lightning. And the response given is, that's an incoherent question

Comment: The responses to the zombie as a thought experiment illustrate that something has gone wrong deeply in the philosophical community at least with regards to HPC. Take the simply idea of someone remote controlling a dummy or a robot. The robot behaves as if it's conscious. A child would understand the question, "is the dummy conscious or not?". These types of scenarios play out in sci-fi shows all the time. People understand them perfectly. But the philosopher talks his way out of the question itself by saying the dummy's behavior IS consciousness itself. Or dismiss the question as incoherent.

Comment: @Conifold, do you think Dennett is genuine? Honestly I think he's trolling. Looking at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeNKAyp4vTQ Dennett keeps repeating the same thing he's been saying for years. 'There's nothing here that requires explaining.' Keith gives the same response I would. It's hard for me to take Dennett seriously.

Comment: @AmeetSharma What do you think of Hammerof’s microtubule explanation? It has improved at least regards to how reasonable the physics sounds (last part of this). But also imo the presentation a bit better: https://youtu.be/gfmcEbD64XY

Comment: @AlBrown, I like the approach because at least it acknowledges that something needs to be changed in physics to allow for the relationship between matter and consciousness. I agree with Penrose's reasoning that the brain is somehow exploiting physics we have not figured out yet that allows for the matter-consciousness connection. I don't like the "consciousness is high level feature of matter" approaches. As far as the actual scientific merits (how closely it fits evidence etc.) I don't know.

Comment: @AmeetSharma I dislike Dennett's dripping condescension, Churchland takes a more serious tone. But the standoff is analogous to the one in ethics. Per Hume, we cannot get norms out of facts alone, so any argument for normative realism has to presuppose some grain of it. Similarly, we cannot get phenomenal aspects out of relational ones alone, so any argument for HPC must appeal to irreducibly phenomenal evidence. And to opponents that just begs the question. Ultimately, physicalists are not interested in parsing now what conscious AI will accomplish some day, they just resist *a priori* limits

Comment: @Conifold 1/2 I read the link, incl especially the reductionist and functionalist, and overlapping, defns of consciousness you provided. In my experience with philosophers and meditators, there is an under appreciation of the role memory plays in experiencing and I would bet even in defining consciousness. If something is happening and has no access to write even to very short-term memory, then that is not going to be a conscious process. I

Comment: @AmeetSharma 2/2 haven’t thought it through well, but it does seem to be a missing component, insufficiently emphasized and usually entirely excluded. I dont know the exact role, but I feel sure it’s fairly big. Im not even sure it makes sense to talk about it without that as a first order aspect.

Comment: Please, no youtube links in questions. You need to summarize in words what it is you are asking about.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I can accept that. I edited the question and removed it.

Comment: Conifold writes: "Part of the hard problem is that there is no agreement on what the hard problem is."  Although I have noticed that there is a great deal of confusion over what the hard problem is, that does not seem to be the case at all among the philosophical cognoscenti.  **The hard problem is to explain why consciousness should exist, based on the physical laws of the universe.** Is that really a controversial definition? I don't think so.

Comment: Maybe so yes. I know you comment on conifold, but I wrote: “How do you explain that first-person, subjective consciousness as a raw, fundamental ontology is here? That qualia exist with their very own raw being, separate from the physical measurables. The hard problem is not simply that ‘We are super complex so how can matter be doing a human?’ Thats the easy problem.” But I added ‘as a separate ontology’ to what you wrote. Also, “why” is answered by some as “because these things function this or that way” not “because it evolved and is needed to fulfill this or that function”.

Comment: The problem is dualists are no closer to an explanation of consciousness than hardcore physicalists. Physicalists say consciousness emerges "somehow", and dualists say there is an ill defined soul thing, that is immaterial yet interact with matter, but only through a human brain for some reason and by some yet to be determined process. The soul experiences and controls the body "somehow", just as "somehow" as the consciousness emerges according to physicalists. What finalists have is at best a research hypothesis, not an explanation.

Comment: @armand What about the view that awareness is all that exists? It seems like if we start with what we actually know. I know there is awareness. This is self-evident, primary, here. (Aside: It’s unfortunate that philosophers have selected “consciousness” rather than awareness. First of all they are different. My notions and what I think has generally been meant by the terms historically: Consciousness is the phenomenon that if you forgot everything and were sitting in a room, what would you know / be able to say? I’m here. (Incidentally most people will give that as an answer). Consciousness.

Comment: 2/2 still the aside: Conscious being pre-conceptual cognition. Knowing that Im a being, the whole context/scenario. Being cognizant of context. Consciousness does not equal awareness. If I say be aware of your hand, you feel the actual sensations. If I say be conscious of your hand you go to context (you might say “why? is something about to fall on it?”). Awareness is the building block of consciousness. End of aside.

Comment: 3/3 @DanielAsim also. But the sense of self is constructed out of thoughts/images/feelings.  And those are MADE of awareness. One realizes phenomena is made of awareness because the lines between the object of sense or perceiving and my sensation or perception and my awareness of the sensation or perception.. those lines do not exist. It’s just awareness. This is really all we know or can know. The content (thoughts conclusions blah blah are second-hand in a sense to the only FACT that awareness is happening. Have you ever encountered anything other than awareness? Is it not the atom of being?

Comment: Back to the aside. But the philosophers who say everything is consciousness should say awareness. (My numbering doesnt matter, in order if expanded. Above i meant if you ask someone what could you say if you had no memory at all. They would answer “I could say ‘I am here.’ ”)

Comment: @albrown I don't think idealism changes anything. Unless you are going with solipsism, there is a reality that is external to us and that we share (we can both agree on how many beads there's in a jar, or the mass of the sun, etc. There is not one mass for you one mass for me.) wether this reality is made of matter or ideas I don't know, but dualists are still claiming there is something out of it but that interact with it, without the beginning of an understanding of the nature of this interaction. In any case, this is no explanation, just ad hoc handwaving.

Comment: How do you know anything? Everything you wrote is second hand and depends upon logic, and most importantly is itself just further phenomena/awareness. What’s it made of? The only thing we know or can know.

Comment: @armand 2/2 I also agree other streams of phenomena/awareness probably happening. Can call that other minds or mind-streams. I also agree it follows patterns, but we don’t know what is behind it, whether it’s made of anything, what reality is, whether matter (which cannot be defined) exists. If the question is asked: what do we know for sure? Could it be a simulation, could it be this or that or whatever. Could be the mind of God. But I know there is knowing. The single verifiable, undeniable reality, that phenomena/awareness is happening. Everything else is conjecture.

Comment: If we dont know anything then furthermore dualist are not anymore close to any explanation than any other school of thought. I may not know what reality is made of, but I know there is one, wether it's a simulation, a collective dream or a material world. You too, if you know there is knowing, you know there is something to know. Hyperbolic doubt without a reason to doubt is just a waste of time.

Comment: @armand The ultimate point is that we know there is this knowing/awareness. Thats what we know for sure.

Comment: (It’s not entirely clear to me that means there is an object of knowing as I can never seem to find the line between the knowing and the known; of course it does vary in flavor/content so we can maybe infer a known, not clear if the changes are in the knowing or the known although we presume the latter. But ok that’s secondary.)

Comment: I bet you live your whole life as if you knew for sure your parents are real people, that you really have hands, that you need breathing, etc... Because the whole world works as if those facts are true, and nothing ever led you to doubt them. This is what certainty means, and this is why all the people who claim to follow Descartes on the path of "the only thing I know is I am because I think" are unable to put their money where their mouth is. I also think we moved very far away from the hard problem of consciousness.

Comment: @armand thanks for the reply. That last one actually makes some real sense to me. Have a great day. 

Comment: Suggested tag, added some links, and typos.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of subjective experience is best divided into two very different questions. First, whether subjective experience exists; and second, if it does, how to explain it in terms of something else and then what.

Many people who seem to be what I call "hardcore materialists" simply deny that subjective experience exists. One way they do that is by asking for a definition of subjective experience. Given that the problem is to explain subjective experience, there is no definition. The only way to identify it is in the same way as you would identify the Moon in the sky by pointing your finger at it, but in the case of subjective experience, it doesn't seem possible to do that. Instead, it is for each of us to privately identify our own subjective experience, and people who cannot or are unwilling to do that can be safely ignored.

The second way to deny that subjective experience exists is to claim that it is illusionary. But illusionary to what? Thus, although it is an absurd argument, many people use it. It is difficult to decide whether these people are particularly obtuse or somehow do not have subjective experience, however surprising that would be.

So, people who one way or the other claim that subjective experience does not exist are best ignored. This leaves only the hard problem of finding a plausible explanation for the existence and characteristics of subjective experience. Personally, I am happy to leave this problem unresolved because I have no good reason to believe that the humain brain should be able to solve it. There is another problem in this category, and this is the problem of explaining the existence and characteristics of reality, reality as a whole, as such. Like for subjective experience, there is no possible explanation. The brain is the result of natural selection and there is no reason to expect it can solve metaphysical problems. We have the brain that we have because it can solve the myriad problems we can face as a living organism in our natural environment. Metaphysical questions may be funny but they are a waste of time.

We should also no confuse the problem of explaining subjective experience and the problem of explaining the information contents of the human mind. Every human being intuitively understands that what happens in his or her mind is intimately connected to what happens in the material world. Hit first your finger hard with a hammer before daring to object to that. So we all know or understand that the contents of our own mind is most plausibly entirely explainable in terms of the physical world. This will be a difficult problem to solve, but not quite as hard as the hard problem of consciousness. The real question, therefore, is to explain the quality of subjective experience, hence the word "qualia" used to help people understand what the question is about. There is no more reason that we should be able to answer this question than we should be able to explain reality in terms of something else.

Still, I understand that philosophers are not going to stop pretending they have something meaningful to say on the subject. Most metaphysical questions were already known and discussed by philosophers in antiquity, certainly in Ancient Greece, and we are still shaking the same empty box just in case something suddenly dropped out.

Comment: Thanks. Thats all good. Esp liked the dismissal of people who deny it exists and the point your finger at the moon. It’s more obvious and real than matter. If by real I mean it is. Not “is correct” or “is accurate”. So illusory isnt an answer. “Illusory to what” as you say.

Comment: “..we are still shaking the same empty box just in case something suddenly dropped out.“ Lol. Love that. But Im not so pessimistic. For one thing I dont know enough to know how true that is. Easy for a novice or beginner to think experts are full of baloney. But I know for sure in some other fields that experts **absolutely are**, so it’s not impossible. Secondly, I do know things are more rigorously defined and stated. That said Ive also seen some big-time repeat. For now my opinion of the field is positive. Not that anyone cares. Theyre way to sure of atheism though, as most in academia

Comment: @AlBrown "*Thanks*" You're welcome. 2. "*Theyre way to sure of atheism though, as most in academia*" What is the connection that the question of the existence and characteristics of subjective experience has with theism?

Comment: No connection. I ended up expressing extremely general opinions and even summarized by saying I have an overall positive view of the current field of philosophy. Except for that large caveat.

Comment: Well I also dont mean to now make a positive statement that theres *no* connection. Havent thought about it. Just saying the idea of any connection was not my reason for bringing it up here. My reason was that I had digressed into overall opinions about current state of philosophy, and so wanted to add the only thing I feel quite certain is quite lame about said state: their level of certainty in their atheism.

Comment: @AlBrown How do you measure the level of certainty of the atheists?

Comment: Speakpigeeon writes: "The real question, therefore, is to explain the quality of subjective experience". I don't know for sure if you are trying to say that this is the real "hard problem of consciousness". But if you are, your choice of words is especially asking for confusion. The "quality" of consciousness — its specific manifestations under various circumstances — is what Chalmers has appropriately termed "the easy problem" (not that it's truly easy). The hard problem is emphatically *not* to explain the "quality" of consciousness, but rather to explain its *existence*.

Comment: @DanielAsimov Sorry, I don't really understand. First, you say "confusion", but then you say it is "the easy problem". You may want to make up your mind. Second, if it is easy to explain the quality of our subjective experience, then please explain it to me, I'm curious. Third, to explain something is to explain its existence, and to explain it in terms of something else, because we don't know how to explain something not in terms of something else except to say that it just exists, as in existence without a cause. Essentially, I think you don't understand my answer.

Comment: Speakpigeon: Try reading what I wrote again, more carefully this time. (And I apologize for mistyping your username last time.)

Comment: @DanielAsimov Sorry, I cannot read your mind.

Comment: Aristotles *Metaphysics* was not an empty box. Averroes said he had to read it fifty times before understanding what it was saying. It's substantially easier now given the work of many scholars. It seeded the scientific revolution in Europe through Averroes. When Newton spoke of "Aristotle is my frirnd and Plato is my friend but truth is a greater friend", he recognised what Aristotle and Plato had to say was valuable and not 'empty'.

Comment: I didn't say that Aristotle's metaphysics was an empty box.

Comment: People denying subjective experience exist, because they cannot point at it in 3rd person, commit 2 mistakes: a) category mistake, b) scientific insincerety

Comment: @NikosM. For most of them, I think it is a sort of hang-up from the long ideological war between materialists and the Church.

Comment: "Many people who seem to be what I call "hardcore materialists" simply deny that subjective experience exists." Please provide the quotations of those materialists who deny the subjective experience. "The second way to deny that subjective experience exists is to claim that it is illusionary. But illusionary to what?" This is **not** the meaning of illusion in the sense the Illusionists use. By illusion, they mean the feeling of irreducibility as if you were to take magician's trick as real unexplainable magic, but the trick is actually explained by the magician's explanation.

Comment: "The real question, therefore, is to explain the quality of subjective experience" It is not the hard problem of consciousness. The hard problem is to explain how and why subjective qualia arise from inanimate matter. (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_problem_of_consciousness) The quality of experience is studied by psychologists, maybe phenomenologists or else.

Comment: @bodhihammer Yes, I know what people say and mean and I sometimes frame the problem in those terms. But my perspective is much more interesting. The quality of subjective experience is not studied by psychologists. They couldn't care less. This is not their problem. If that was their problem, they could study the quality of their own subjective experience and this is certainly not what psychologists do.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents and then some.

The "hard problem" is really hard, I would say insoluble only for a certain point of view. The point of view that accepts only a certain explanatory framework (eg current physics) and at the same time accepting a *gap* regarding subjective experience being reducible in that framework. Some refer to this (Galen Strawson<sup>1</sup>, for example) as physicSalism (in contrast to physicalism).

Physicalism, according to Strawson accepts that experience is physical and  irreducible (a basic fact of physical reality).

On the other hand, physicSalism wants to reduce experience to whatever one would like to see as more basic, eg charge or mass , etc.

There are serious arguments against proposals such as emergence, for this to happen.

Now this situation is really hard,.

Another approach, taken by illusionism, is to outright deny there is a gap, by denying subjective experience really exists.

So the hard problem is actually hard for some approaches, for other approaches is in fact a non-problem.

This has been termed the *meta problem of consciousness*, meaning the reasons some think there is any hard problem at all<sup>2</sup>.

1. [Realistic Monism: Why Physicalism Entails Panpsychism, by Galen Strawson](https://www.sjsu.edu/people/anand.vaidya/courses/c2/s0/Realistic-Monism---Why-Physicalism-Entails-Panpsychism-Galen-Strawson.pdf)
2. [The Meta-Problem of Consciousness, by David Chalmers](https://philpapers.org/archive/CHATMO-32.pdf)

**ADDENDUM**

Consider Newton's 2nd Law: **f = ma**.

This mathematical relation is the basis of the current scientific paradigm.

What does it mean really?

It relates **force** to **acceleration** (and vice-versa). In some sense it relates cause and effect (force being the cause, acceleration being the effect). For every force applied there will be such and such acceleration as outcome.

But the opposite is also true, for example in non-inertial frames of reference, acceleration in fact induces force (sometimes caled apparent forces, but as real as any force can be).

Moreover the relation has been used as the general definition of force, or simply as an operational relation.

So what gives? Can it be said that force is reduced to acceleration, or not?

Suppose now that a future experiment leads to the formulation, resembling the best of current scientific paradigm, that: **e = mx**. **e** being some "quantity of experience" and **x** being some other quantity.

Does the formulation of such scientifically impeccable relation justify reductionist position of experience or non-reductionist position?

I am of the opinion that such relations (if ever found) can be used to justify any of the two positions and becomes a matter of dominant interpretation (as has been the case, for example, in Quantum Mechanics).

What all this wants to illustrate, is that the debate may simply be lost in translation, as there can be outcomes which are perfectly valid according to current scientfic paradigm, yet can be interpreted in completely different ways.

Comment: Yes excellent point at the end. I didnt know about physicsalism. I used to be an almost aggressive materialist. What finally did me in was trying to explain true as opposed to false, then explain what a statement or claim is (where it is, what it is) if only matter exists. For me, correspondence failed to capture it. Realized assertions cannot exist, true and false cannot exist, knowing cannot exist. This now seems so solid and obvious to me. Beyond that, I dont know what reality is. But if it is only physical, no one can say so or know it and there is no truth, so physicalism isnt even true.

Comment: Added the reference, check it out.

Comment: Couple years later Im back on stackexchange. Thanks for the added reference. In reading your reply again, it all made sense to me. Yes the hard problem is by definition unsolvable. “Presuming that only the physical exists, explain nonphysical consciousness existing - which (the hard problem asserts) clearly DOES exist and clearly IS nonphysical.” Lol. Even seems silly to me now. The hard problem is not a question; it’s really just a statement. The statement that physicalism is false. (Which it is)

Answer (score 3):

> the issue is that materialists and physicalists presume a different
> question and answer that one instead.
>
> I feel like the two parties are talking across each other.

They are all on the same page but they propose different solutions. Will any solution suffice, however? That is important.

> **Q1**: Do dualists or other monists (consciousness, ideal) reply to
> phenomenal descriptions of consciousness by saying, “Youre not
> actually answering the hard problem.” ?

The hard problem only arises if you accept the gap between matter and mind. The Hard Problem is the artefact largely rooted in Cartesian dilemmas, as explained by Chalmers.

For a large majority of monists, there is no Hard Problem to start with **and this is the solution**.

The two common variants of monism are idealism and physicalism. The former says All is Mind, the latter All is Matter. The hard problem does not arise for monists who are reductionists; materialists such as Dennett, Papineau, or idealists like Kastrup. (There is also neutral monism, i.e. that of Donald Davidson or Baruch Spinoza, or that of panpsychism.)

Dualists and non-reductionists are the "gappists". They think there is seemingly an unsurpassable gap between the matter and mind and we cannot grasp how a pack of neurons can produce a mind. Those philosophers sometimes introduce another [property of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_dualism), or [a whole new substance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactionism_(philosophy_of_mind)) to account for consciousness.

The critique from monists–those who deny the gap–is that, if you have put yourself in this losing position where you make such a claim, then you can never make any progress. You made the gap mystical, ineffable and unsurpassable. You might never be able to answer the question, nor make any scientific progress towards it if you accept no solutions from the only ones which are available. D. Dennet, for instance, claims that we should proceed and only answer the "important" hard questions, which are also extremely hard but are the only questions we might meaningfully answer. Perhaps, he says, we should exhaust the existing possibilities and only then pose "magical" stuff (Churchlands, Dennett). The critique from idealist monists is also prevalent:

> The hard problem of consciousness is not a problem that needs to be
> solved, for it doesn’t exist in any objective sense. It is merely an
> internal contradiction of the reasoning behind metaphysical
> materialism, a conceptual short-circuit that arises as we logically
> work out the implications of the materialist conception of matter. [1](https://iai.tv/articles/matter-is-nothing-more-than-the-extrinsic-appearance-of-inner-experience-auid-1372)

In idealists' eyes, this is not a real problem.

> **Q2**: Am I capturing what it is they are said to be missing?
> Alternatively, the second question might even be, “Would philosophers
> agree with, and even make, the distinctions I make?” about the hard
> problem.

I have "pushed back" a little, as you see. Philosophers either do or don't accept the hard problem (but they all agree on its definition).

> Dennett and others then proceed with ever more complex (and possibly
> ever more accurate) physical models/descriptions of biological
> functioning, mechanisms of the processing of perception, etc.
>
> Dennet has most recently been saying we are like a trillion little
> robots who “accomplish” consciousness:
>
> Elsewhere he says “gives rise to”.

Not necessarily. Dennet doesn't just give more complex descriptions. Dennett tries to have a theory of consciousness having existing (however limited) resources. Other illusionist philosophers like K. Frankish, the Churchlands, or neuroscientists like Michael S.A. Graziano, Anil Seth also have different solutions and theories which try to explain the "hard question" ([**not** a hard problem](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstb.2017.0342)).

(Since you mentioned Dennett, he is essentially a first-wave identity theorist (Read: [Introduction section from "Illusionism"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/37786277-illusionism)), but those philosophers had to differentiate themselves from second-wave identity theorists that sometimes proposed additional quasi-states which are not directly observed via empirical sciences ([Papineau](https://www.keithfrankish.com/2021/04/comment-on-papineau-vs-dennett/)).)

For Dennet, in his Multiple Draft model, mature consciousness is achieved through the brain implementing a so-called [Joycean Virtual Machine](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/books/98/12/06/specials/dennett-consciousness.html?source=post_page---------------------------), which is a specific operating system software in the brain that has the linguistic capacity. It implements and controls self-monitoring and self-narrative, essentially producing what we call self-consciousness. As you see this is a theory that hypothesises a concrete software-like faculty in the brain "giving rise" to consciousness. It does not propose additional ontological property aside from what we know from natural sciences.

> However, no philosophical dualist (nor monist idealist) is arguing
> that it cannot be “accomplished” by the trillion robots.

They do, of course, argue that it cannot be accomplished. For example, those philosophers use Searle's [Chinese Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_brain) and [Chinese Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room) experiments against Dennett's claim. Those thought experiments were meant to invalidate "trillion robots claim".

Idealists also deny that "trillion robots" can achieve it. For idealists, it is completely the other way around than how Dennett has it. Mind is the ontological primitive. Your mind is projecting (representing) itself into the *phenomenal* world. It can be the intellect faculty that is projected (represented) as the prefrontal cortex or the emotional states (qualias) that are represented as your Endocrine system, and so forth. For monist idealists, Dennett's claim is backwards as the trillion neurons are just the pixels of your desktop screen through which you see everything. It is Mind that makes them, not the other way around.

> Q3: Would addressing those numbered questions answer the problem? Is
> that the kind of thing people say?

Since I think I answered your questions already I will ask another question, as an exercise of "pushing back".

The very question is, instead, whether any answer to the problem would satisfy a sceptic*? Is there any explanation that could eliminate the gap for sceptics? I doubt that. This is why reductionism will not succeed even if it is true that there is no gap because people would simply not accept these claims. That is an impossible situation.

*- i.e. Dualist or non-reductionist.

Comment: +1 for pushing back on dualism. Certainly Dennett via Ryle would endorse!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Just seeing it. I reproduce for you a reply I made above: Couple years later Im back on stackexchange. Thanks for the added reference. In reading your reply again, it all made sense to me. Yes the hard problem is by definition unsolvable. “Presuming that only the physical exists, explain nonphysical consciousness existing - which (the hard problem asserts) clearly DOES exist and clearly IS nonphysical.” Lol. Even seems silly to me now. The hard problem is not a question; it’s really just a statement. The statement that physicalism is false. (i add imo it is false)

Comment: I disagree with your answer, but still call it great and see many interesting things Im still working through. Also see the same theme in your answer as the answer above that made me initially reply with the comment i reproduced

Comment: And hence your statement that physicalists must assert there is no hard problem, esp as stated in my reply. They are merely asserting physicalism by doing so. (I guess it could really only apply and be interesting for property dualists whom you allude to.. since it doesnt exist for physicalists and is already solved for dualists and idealists. Do you agree?)

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend two relatively recent works on this issue.

One is Kim's [*Physicalism, or Something Near Enough*](http://m). Kim discusses the last 60 years effort to try to fit consciousness into physicalism.  His conclusion:  the anti-physicalists have won the day.  NONE of the physicalist "solutions" convinces anyone outside the small sliver of the advocates of that particular perspective.  In other words, there is a wide consensus that all of the physicalist "solutions" are wrong except for one, but there is absolutely no agreement on which one that is ...

Kim, unfortunately, in his own personal proposal adopts a fusion approach to consciousness -- part of it is functional, and that part is reductive to neural identity theory (Kim admits that functional identity theory, if it is to be different from neural identity theory, is actually a function/matter dualism), and part is epiphenomenal qualia that are not physical.  Why consciousness would have these two very different aspects, and how they would be so intertwined, and the rationale for one-way causation to qualia but not back-causation from them -- none of this is explained in the too-brief latter part of the book.  But his explanation of the history of the problem is excellent.

I can also recommend Hankin's [*A Shadow of Consciousness*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Shadow_of_Consciousness/4Go5rgEACAAJ?hl=en). Haskins details the various problems discovered in the last 40-year effort to solve both the easy problem and the hard problem of consciousness. Interestingly, the failures to solve the easy problem have been almost as thorough as the failures to solve the hard problem. Recognizing goodness, and selecting for it, is a problem that logic systems flounder over.  Hankins is a sympathetic summarizer, and proposes a set of possibly useful directions for both efforts to try next.

OK, trying to answer your three questions based on this background --

> Q1: Do dualists or other monists (consciousness, ideal) reply to
> phenomenal descriptions of consciousness by saying, “You're not
> actually answering the hard problem.” ?

The actual answer is that it is not just dualists who reject the solutions -- competing materialists also do so.  Specifically, the arguments are that there are refuting examples or test cases, that each of the proposed solutions fails to deal with.  Eliminative reductionism, neural identity theory, functional identity theory, delusionism, dual aspect theory, epiphenomenalism -- each is rejected by their competitors for very good reasons -- not just by dualists.

The proposals generally admit there was an at least APPARENT hard problem, then generally propose a method to dissolve the problem.  But when the method fails, the hard problem remains.

> Q2: Am I capturing what it is they are said to be missing?
> Alternatively, the second question might even be, “Would philosophers
> agree with, and even make, the distinctions I make?” about the hard
> problem.

No, you leapt to a solution, when you said it was an ontological problem with qualia existing. Your summary:

> How do you explain that first-person, subjective consciousness as a
> raw, fundamental ontology is here? That qualia exist with their very
> own raw being, separate from the physical measurables.

Can only be accepted by abandoning physicalism.

The hard problem is that we HAVE the immediate experience of qualia, and there appears to be no way to coherently reconcile/explain this with physicalism. Don't put your solution in the statement of the problem!

More questions:

> Are they 1: just different names for the same thing (the trillions of
> robots and the subjective experience) or are they 2. in
> cause-and-effect relation (as normally implied by “accomplished”)
> within a single ontological category, or does 3. this causation
> somehow cross ontological categories?

Most physicalists assert 1.  Many emergent non-reductive physicalists, and all epiphenomenalists, assert 2.  3 isn't physicalism, it is dualism. The most popular current dualism is emergent psycho-physical dualism, with two-way interaction. This is a non-spooky naturalist dualism.

> Q3: Would addressing those numbered questions answer the problem? Is
> that the kind of thing people say? I imagine many readers of this
> question will want to argue that it doesn't miss the hard problem.
> That’s perfectly ok, but I am really asking what the philosophers who
> counter, who think it misses, would say. And if it matches some of the
> above or what?

Kim provided the best answer here.  Physicalists have been treating the hard problem seriously for more than a century and most of them are honest enough to say that all of the rival physical theories (except for perhaps one ... ) fail to actually answer the hard problem.  You will have a few dogmatists out there who insist their answer is definitive -- see Dennett as an example -- but their colleagues' consensus is that the dogmatists are wrong.

Comment: I read Kim's book a while ago and his solution is similar to Ned Block's one, where raw qualias are analogue, whereas everything else that can be functionally explained (quantitatively) is functionalist. Forgive me, but in my view, this is no answer at all. His diagrams that use the Aristotlean-borrowed kind of causality (P1 -causes-> P2) are in my opinion wrong since we know that this is not at all the case that objects self-cause their consecutive states (P1 to P2) on the physical level (as in essentialism).

Comment: @bodhihammer -- Kim's "solution" is uncredible enough that it degrades the overall quality of the book.  I mentioned it as a perhaps inappropriate tangent.  The history and summary of consensus is what I cited the book for.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link to Hankin's book. :D

Answer (score 1):

Since Dennett doesn't believe in mind, it's not surprising that he thinks of humans as 'robots'. Personally, I think this is a good reason not to believe in Dennett: his solution is worse than the problem.

The hard problem is to explain mind, no one has done a good job of it. Chalmers, who popularised the the hard problem in recent times says he was forced to panpsychism, this is an admixture of mind and matter. But this position was already explained in Plato's *Timeaus* where *nous* (intellect) and *ananke* (necessity, or the abstract principle of matter) intermingled to create the universe. Democritus - the inventor of atoms - who is usually seen as a hard materialist by his modern readers also picked up on this through his notion of 'soul atoms' and the early modern incarnation of this is Leibniz's monads.

Comment: I find posts a lot easier to read when they don't misspell names of famous philosophers and names of famous pieces of philosophy.

Comment: Dennett doesn't characterize people as robots. He characterizes the mind as emerging illusorily from an assembly of neurological components devoid of intentionality. Dennett gets together every year with his religious friends at Christmas and sings hymns to celebrate life. This is not the practice who believes humans are robots.

Comment: Great thoughts. Thank you

Comment: @Daniel Asimov: I have a hard time going back on my posts and editing them to journal level quality when I'm not paid for my time. Why don't you take that up with the management of stack exchange who are earning their millions on the unpaid labour of a large pool of volunteers? Or is that too difficult a job for you? Or is that because you'd be unpaid doing that particular job? Well now you see my point.

Comment: @J D: You're simply playing with words. When the mind is emerges "illusionary" then it doesn't exist as such. Illusion is akin to a lie or a trick. This is why mirages are described as illusions as they are a trick of the light. It's also why magicians tricks are described as illusions because they are done by tricky sleight-of-hand.

Comment: "Since Dennett doesn't believe in mind" it is a typical misrepresentation of Dennett's views. Nowhere does Dennett claim that mind doesn't exist or that consciousness isn't real.

Comment: @bodhihammer: The SEP describes Dennett as a modest eliminativist. An eliminativist being someone who denies the existence of the mind.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Dennett is not this kind of eliminativist. Moreover, he is vehemently against this kind of eliminativism about mind (See: podcast with Sean Carroll). Dennett is only eliminativist about the particular description of qualia as ineffable/unexplainable fundamental properties with which we get direct acquaintance with.

Comment: @bodhihammer: The SEP is an authoritative guide to philosophy. If they're prepared to describe him as an eliminativist, modest orvnot, then I don't see why it is problematic to describe him as such. For sure, my post is a little polemical but as a writer I expect Dennett to understand that.

Comment: @MoziburUllah This isn't about eliminativism. The claim that you made that Dennett denies mind or consciousness is false. I think Dennett is an authoritative guide to his own philosophy:  "No, we Deniers do not say this. We say that there isn’t any conscious experience (...) that involve[s] being “directly acquainted,”(...) with some fundamental properties (“qualia”), this is an illusion, a philosopher’s illusion (...) I don’t deny the existence of consciousness; of course, consciousness exists; it just isn’t what most people think it is, as I have said many times."

Comment: @bodhihammer: What part of 'modest eliminativist' did you not understand? It's rather like saying Christian with a small c. It doesn't mean that they aren't Christians but that they are modest Christians. Likewise with Dennett as a mind-denying eliminativist. Qualia is taken by some philosophers interested in the philosophy of mind, like Chalmers, to be one of the key attributes of experience. By denying it, Dennett is definitely standing in the eliminativist camp - even if modestly so.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You are doing rather poor whataboutism here. Again, the claim 'Dennett doesn't believe in mind' is false. It is simply that. Daniel Dennett is **not** a mind-denying eliminativist, and he explicitly said so many *many* times. You seem to be quite oblivious about what Dennett actually claims, philosophically speaking. You are interested in presenting a simplistic caricature view that is simply misrepresentation of his views.

Answer (score 1):

For monists and panpsychists, there is no division between matter and consciousness. Therefore, there is no hard problem. The fundamental stuff of the universe is matter-consciousness. Consciousness is fundamental not emergent. I recommend Strawson, Chalmers, Goff. Also the paper in Entropy in January by Hoffman et al. In my view, the hard problem is the longest dead-end in modern philosophy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now agree. I reproduce part of my comment from below: At the risk of being trite, we could restate HPC as: “Presuming that only the physical exists, explain nonphysical consciousness existing - which (the hard problem asserts) clearly DOES exist and clearly IS nonphysical.” Even seems silly to me now. The hard problem is not a question; it’s really just a statement. The statement that physicalism is false. (Which it is)

Comment: Thank you. Yet a lot of time is spent on a non-existent problem.